# Can I not to count some method in total Unit Test TestMethod time output?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit TestClass with several TestMethods in it (all of them are counting db procedure perfomance). Some method includes a large and heavy preparation part. Such as it's longer than method itself. Can I somehow make vs to not include it's time into total timeout of whole unittest method?

I try to use method with ClassInitialize attribute, but:

1. It brokes with ThreadAbortException, saying "Thread was being
       aborted".
2. As I [Understand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx) it's time is added to time of first test
       method.

Comment: unit tests aren't really good for testing performance.

Comment: What is the purpose of your tests? If you don't want something executing in your test - mock it away!

Comment: Try executing the code in the constructor of the test class. This way you can prepare some variables before the unit test execution time starts.

Answer (score -1):

One way I can think of is to create a separate TestMethod that never makes any assertions, and performs the preparation.  Then make sure this method is always invoked prior to the actual test.

However, for testing performance, you may want to look into using some Profiling Tools as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It not only solves the problem as presented by the OP, but it also highlights the fact that there are better ways to do this (without forcing it down the OPs throat).